# Two separate menus in silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe

I recently started to use SilverStripe. RIght now i made a footer menu for my page where already have a left menu. Now i want to make that i can make pages in admin panel for foot and left menu. So my idea was to made a check box in admin panel, if you make a new page and check the checkbox the page go in foot menu, if leave empty then in left menu.

I add this code to my page.php sidetree

```
 static $db = array( 'menuLocationHorizontal' => "Boolean" );
```

And this in getCMSFields in page.php

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Behaviour', new 
   CheckboxField('menuLocationHorizontal',"Show up in horizontal 
   menu?"),"ShowInSearch");
```

This is how looks my footnav template

```
<ul>
    <% control Menu(2) %>    
    <% if menuLocationHorizontal == 1 %> 
        <li><a href="$Link" title="Go to the $Title.XML page" class="$LinkingMode"><span>$MenuTitle.XML</span></a></li>
         <% end_if %>
    <% end_control %>
</ul>
```

After i done this i just add an if statment in my foot menu and thats it. But it crashes the site. Version i use is 3.1. I guess its php foult.
Sorry guys for my English, it is not my native.

Comment: You might have a look at the https://github.com/heyday/silverstripe-menumanager/tree/2.0 module where you can define seperate menus from Pages.

Comment: Thanks i added this in but it wont work. I maka a new menuset it shows me internal server error , but it stills make the menu_set and after that i cant edit the sets

Answer (score 0):

`control` entries are not supported on SS 3.1, what you're looking for is a `<% loop %>`, like so:

```
<ul>
  <% loop Menu(2) %>    
    <% if menuLocationHorizontal == 1 %> 
      <li><a href="$Link" title="Go to the $Title.XML page" class="$LinkingMode"><span>$MenuTitle.XML</span></a></li>
    <% end_if %>
  <% end_loop %>
</ul>
```

More information available on [Silverstripe docs website](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/templates/syntax/#looping-over-lists).

Comment: Ok thank you i fix this. But still i cant add this 'menuLocationHorizontal' => "Boolean" , it crashed the site.

Comment: "Crashed the site"... what error message did you get @Thranduil ?

Comment: I get internal server error in admin panel when i am trying to acces pages and my start pages shows - Server error Sorry, there was a problem with handling your request.

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was this -> https://github.com/i-lateral/silverstripe-custommenus
The only thing that actually worked.

Comment: Glad you found a solution then :) Worth noting though that the module's readme suggests that SS 3.1 is not supported: "SilverStripe 3.3 or greater."

Comment: I know, but i try your model, it wont work. I get only errors.